# handeing outliers in sale data

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, outliers

I have a transaction data which include extremes. In fact I want to keep this part of data rather than remove them. So first by tukey method(IOR) outliers were detected. At this stage, I want to know is it possible that implement clustering algorithm to analyze them separately? So in this way I would have clusters which comes from outliers as well as other clusters which comes from my remained data. As I want to mention this method as part of my preprocessing phase in an article, I could not find a reliable reference for that. I'd be appreciated if I can have your feedbacks, thanks
(in case any code recommendation, I work with paython3)

Comment: Seems like you could run the same analysis algorithm on both datasets separately and then combine the results in the end

Comment: @LiorPollak yes exactly, but i'm  not sure how much is it common.  i'm looking the way that could be justifiable for article reviewers. do you think this method work?